# Is there a jQuery widget equal to DOJO's TitlePane?

Tags: jquery, accordion, dojo

I like the visual behavior of the DOJO TitlePane widget, but it has too much other bunk for my purpose. http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/TitlePane.html#dijit-titlepane

Is anyone aware of a jQuery widget that provides the same ability to expose and hide content in a stacked manner with the little flippy-arrow, pane highlighting on mouse over, etc? An accordion does not accomplish my goal being able to have multiple panes open at the same time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An Accordion with just one pane and collapsible set to true? http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#collapsible

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, the accordion docs say not to do that. We went ahead and just wrote our own code.